# Loading fields of a node

Tags: views, ajax

I have a simple content type, which contains the fields:

- Title
- Body

In my view the titles of the above content type are listed. When I click on a title, I want the body of the corresponding node to be loaded with AJAX and appended after the title.

Has anyone a hint for me, how to accomplish that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use built-in Drupal Ajax framework.. Steps:

- implement [hook_menu](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7)
- build ajax callback
- render links (titles) like `/[menu callback menu item]/nojs/arguments` and add class `use-ajax`

Here is a good tutorial: [A little Ajax-driven article reader built with the Drupal Ajax framework](https://github.com/seanbuscay/drupal-ajax-demo)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Views Accordion](https://drupal.org/project/views_accordion) module for the same. Module uses jquery accordion style plugin to show hide contents. It's not exactly what you are looking for since module uses hide and show concept instead of Ajax calls to load content. But User Experience wise good option.

Project Pages says

> Views Accordion provides a display style plugin for the Views module.
>   It will take the results and display them as a JQuery accordion, using
>   the first field as the header for the accordion rows.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but as there are multiple images in the body an Ajax call is needed due to loading times.